# Possible to use iPhone(iOS) as a webcam on Ubuntu?

Tags: webcam, iphone

I have a work issued iPhone X I'd love to use as a webcam on my machine.  Has anyone had success doing this?  What software stack was used?

Comment: You must export or share or stream the camera using an iOS app. The phone is not a dumb external device - it's a fiendishly clever, powerful computer *pretending* under very limited circumstances to be an external device.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [Iriun](https://iriun.com/) to do this. You will need to download the [app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/iriun-webcam-for-pc-and-mac/id1439303579) to your iPhone and install the [linux client](http://iriun.gitlab.io/iriunwebcam.deb) (a .deb file for Ubuntu 18.04 or higher).

If what's above doesn't work you can try to use [Droidcam](https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linux/) instead. Follow the instructions to set up the client in the previous link and then download the Droidcam [app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/droidcam-wireless-webcam/id1510258102) on your iphone from the App Store!

Comment: I was off to a great start.  Sadly, even though both devices are on the same wifi network, the server is not finding the phone where I have the app installed and running.

Comment: @Eddiefiggie huh, seems like a bug to me. Maybe try reinstalling the iPhone app or  restarting both computers..

Comment: Same here. iPhone app says "Waiting for the connection" and Ubuntu app says "No phone available". Reinstalled both but still no connection.  Instead, I was able to get a different app -- [DroidCam](https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linux/) -- working. :-)

Comment: @sh37211 Thanks I updated my answer!

Comment: You save my day.